# Xamarin.Auth AccountStore FindAccountForService returning inconsistent results

Tags: c#, xamarin

I create and save an account like so:

```
var account = new Account(PasscodeAccountName, new Dictionary<string, string>{{PasscodeDictKey, passcode}});
AccountStore.Create(_context).Save(account, PasscodeServiceId);
```

If I immediately query for accounts for that serviceId, I get back the account I just created. If I background and then reopen the app (while still debugging) the `FindAccountsForService()` returns zero accounts.